# How to reverse order nested dictionary in python3?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, reverse, simplejson

Apologies if similar question was already asked though I've not been able to find answers after comprehensive googling. I've been struggling with exporting following dictionary into a JSON file with keys ordered in descending order. The file needs to be readable outside Python, thus pickle can't be used.

I'm using Python3.7 and I've tried using simplejson and json libraries to dump the nested dict into a json file, though have been unsuccessful. Pickle seemed to work, though that exports a binary file which is unreadable outside Python. Dict is called 'existing'.

```
with open('Entries_2.json', 'w') as outfile:
    simplejson.dump(existing,outfile,item_sort_key=simplejson.simple_first)
outfile.close()

with open('Entries.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(existing, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
outfile.close()
```

Both of the above methods produce same result:

```
{
    "Entries": {
        "2019/01/23": {
            "Result-9595905890": {
                "count": 4,
                "time": "2019/01/23 03:32:32"
            }
        },
        "2019/01/24": {
            "Result-9607169713": {
                "count": 21,
                "time": "2019/01/24 03:31:34"
            },
            "Result-9611777668": {
                "count": 23,
                "time": "2019/01/24 12:58:49"
            }
        },
        "2019/01/25": {
            "Result-9618433556": {
                "count": 21,
                "time": "2019/01/25 03:31:27"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Though reverse=True option doesn't work in either dump option.
What I need is:

```
{
    "Entries": {
        "2019/01/25": {
            "Result-9618433556": {
                "count": 21,
                "time": "2019/01/25 03:31:27"
            }
        },
        "2019/01/24": {
            "Result-9607169713": {
                "count": 21,
                "time": "2019/01/24 03:31:34"
            },
            "Result-9611777668": {
                "count": 23,
                "time": "2019/01/24 12:58:49"
            }
        },
        "2019/01/23": {
            "Result-9595905890": {
                "count": 4,
                "time": "2019/01/23 03:32:32"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone come across similar struggles?

Comment: why the same? you show not the same.

Comment: Thanks for good spot @BearBrown. I've edited the post.

Comment: You shouldn't be depending on keys being in any particular order in a json object. If you need order, use an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
import json, collections

existing = {
    "Entries": {
        "2019/01/23": {
            "Result-9595905890": {
                "count": 4,
                "time": "2019/01/23 03:32:32"
            }
        },
        "2019/01/24": {
            "Result-9607169713": {
                "count": 21,
                "time": "2019/01/24 03:31:34"
            },
            "Result-9611777668": {
                "count": 23,
                "time": "2019/01/24 12:58:49"
            }
        },
        "2019/01/25": {
            "Result-9618433556": {
                "count": 21,
                "time": "2019/01/25 03:31:27"
            }
        }
    }
}

new_entries = collections.OrderedDict(reversed(sorted(existing['Entries'].items()))) # if you want reversed sorted
existing['Entries'] = new_entries

with open('Entries.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(existing, outfile, indent=4)
```

BTW, when you do `with open('Entries.json', 'w') as outfile:` it will automatically close outfile after the with statement is completed, so you don't need to explicitly close it.

Output:

```
{
    "Entries": {
        "2019/01/25": {
            "Result-9618433556": {
                "count": 21,
                "time": "2019/01/25 03:31:27"
            }
        },
        "2019/01/24": {
            "Result-9607169713": {
                "count": 21,
                "time": "2019/01/24 03:31:34"
            },
            "Result-9611777668": {
                "count": 23,
                "time": "2019/01/24 12:58:49"
            }
        },
        "2019/01/23": {
            "Result-9595905890": {
                "count": 4,
                "time": "2019/01/23 03:32:32"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, it looks good, though when I've tried this inside my code and as a separate script, I always got the same result - the original ordering that was parsed in.
Also, # existing option gave me "TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not reversible" error

Comment: Sorry about that, the previous solution was Python 2.7, I've updated my solution for Python 3. The new solution no longer mixes up the sub-dictionaries. Let me know if it works for you.